# Adding or removing to or from

Tags: prepositions

The sentence

> We wish to verify that adding or removing an apple to the basket does not alter its color.

sounds wrong, because we should *remove from* instead of *remove to*.

But the sentence

> We wish to verify that adding or removing an apple to or from the basket does not alter its color.

sounds complicated.. and lame. But I am not a native speaker.

Is one of the two above correct?
Is there another consensual formulation in this case?
Do I need to hard-rephrase all the sentence?

Comment: Logically, it should be 'adding an apple to, or removing one from, the basket...', but I agree that that sounds over-complicated. If you have already established that the apples are in a basket, why not just say 'adding or removing an apple'?

Comment: does not alter its color is ambiguous. The color of the apple or basket? I would follow Kate's advice.

Comment: It should be obvious that you are on the wrong site.  Try English Language Learners.

Comment: We wish to verify that adding an apple to, or removing one from the basket does not alter its colour.

Comment: @Lambie You're right in this case. But I can guarantee that there is no ambiguity in my actual context (disclaimer: I was not actually writing about apples and basket X) Instead of `color`, just make sure to pick a property that just *cannot* refer to `apples` ;)

Comment: @KateBunting I think you've got the right way to go. Thank you :)

Comment: Careful with the antecedent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second version is probably more formal, but I think most people just accept that it's too cumbersome to use both prepositions. The sentence sounds most natural to me if you use the preposition appropriate for the last verb.

> We wish to verify that adding or removing an apple from the basket does not alter its color.

Comment: I like how light this feels. I'll use this if the solution of @KateBunting turns out not to be possible. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would split your sentence in two separate pieces :

> We wish to verify that adding an apple to the basket or removing one does not alter its color.

Comment: Thank you for this useful rephrasing :)

Answer (score -2):

You should use a comma following a [participial phrase that introduces a sentence](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/):

> We wish to verify that, adding or removing an apple from the basket does not alter its colour.

You want to verify that something you have already done - "adding or removing the apple", did not have an effect on the apple's colour.

> We wish to verify [if], adding or removing an apple from the basket [will] alter its colour.

You want to check if a proposed course of action is likely to have an effect on the apple's colour.

The comma helps to avoid ambiguity, for instance:

> The bear eats, shoots and leaves.

is a completely different [lunchtime homicide] event, compared with:

> The bear eats shoots and leaves

Comment: I disagree with those commas. You would do that if the commas were surrounding a prepositional phrase, e.g. "verify that, after adding or removing an apple, it doesn't change color"

Comment: None of this actually answers the question about the prepositions *from* and *to*.

Comment: Well you are entitled to you opinion, but it is only that.  Did you view the hyper link to Grammarly.com who seem to agree with me ? 
 See also: https://www.istc.org.uk/

Comment: "We with to verify that" is not a participial phrase. Look at the examples at Grammarly, it's not similar.